# browserify.add behaves differently when passing a stream instead of a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, browserify

I'm trying to inline preconfguration data into a dynamically generated script bundled using `browserify`.

To do so I generate a "module" string like:

```
const moduleString = `module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(configurationData)};`;
```

Now I'd like to pass this to [`browserify.add`](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#baddfile-opts). First option would be to write the string to a file, generate the bundle and delete the temp file. This works, but feels tedious.

So I thought of pushing the data to a read stream:

```
var dataModuleStream = new stream.Readable();
dataModuleStream.push(moduleString);
dataModuleStream.push(null);
```

and then pass this to the `.add` call:

```
b.add(dataModuleStream, {expose: 'config'});
```

This also works and inlines the correct data as a module named `config` into the bundle, yet when I try to require that module from my application script:

```
var config = require('config');
```

browserify fails with the error message:

```
Cannot find module 'config' from '/foo/bar/baz'
```

which won't happen when I use the temp file approach. When using the stream and I omit the require call the file will get built, including a module named `config`.

Will my approach even work? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Any resolution or progress on this issue @m90?

Comment: Unfortunately not, no. We are using a temp file approach now. I never got it to work.

Comment: I was able to use a stream by passing it `browserify` instead of `browserify.add` : https://gist.github.com/shawninder/24ff053c202aa50379007ab2603ca453

Hope this is useful